# Trying to understand list selection in MvvM pattern with ICommands (no specific framework)

Tags: mvvm, icommand

First note that I am not referring to any specific framework or technology like XAML.
The question is how to implement the MvvM pattern using `ICommand` for selection of an item in a list (=clicking a row)?

I have a view model (pseudo code):

```
class ListViewModel
{
// Items in the list.
public ObservableCollection<T> Items {};

// Command for item selection.
public ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
{
...
}

// Select an item in the list.
public void SelectItem(int index)
{
...
}

// The current selected item.
public T SelectedItem
{
 get { ... };
}
}
```

How would I now connect my UI to that view model "manually"? Say, for instance in an iOS application.
I would probably have a `UITableViewController`, get an instance of the view model and populate the `UITableView` contents from it. Then I would trigger the `ICommand` from the `RowSelected()` method.
And here comes the thing I don't understand: how does the view model now know which item index was selected? I don't want to call `SelectItem()` because then I would not need the loosely coupled `ICommand` at all.
And maybe here we have to look how it is solved in XAML to understand the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from XAML and WPF, there are two options to forward selection changes from the UI to the ViewModel (as I understand your question, you're not asking about the other way around - feedbacking changes in the ViewModel to the UI - here):

**Command with payload**

The `ICommand`s `Execute` method has a payload parameter. Executing a command without a payload can be done passing null:

```
SomeCommand.Execute(null);
```

In your case, it would make sense to pass the selected item as the parameter in the event handler:

```
vm.ItemSelectedCommand.Execute(eventArgs.SelectedItem);
```

or

```
vm.ItemSelectedCommand.Execute(myList.SelectedItem);
```

In the command's execution method, you can handle the parameter. Note that your ViewModel property `SelectedItem` is not directly involved here. If you need the selected index explicitly (which is not the case, usually), I would check the selected item's index in the `Items` collection.

**Binding selected item of list to a ViewModel property**

Option B is to 'bind' the selected item of the list to a distinct property on the ViewModel, in your case the *SelectedItem* property in the event handler of the list:

```
vm.SelectedItem = myList.SelectedItem;
```

The command is kind of redundant then, although you could invoke it without a payload after setting SelectedItem on the ViewModel. I would rather handle the change of the selected item in the set accessor of the property on the ViewModel.

*Note: XAML and WPF come with quite a lot of infrastructure code out of the box. MVVM doesn't make sense without a proper framework to actually take care of binding UI and ViewModels in a loosely coupled way. You quickly end up with a lot of extra work and little benefit, because you're still maintaining tight dependencies. Bottom line: I recommend getting or writing a proper MVVM framework, before actually implementing it.*

Comment: I have meanwhile noticed the payload parameter. In fact, I forgot about it! Implemented now like you proposed.